# how to compare ids and dates from one csv file to another?

Tags: java, algorithm, oop, conditional-statements, structure

I am working on a task where I have 2 files named file1.csv and file2.csv with columns ids and dates.

Let's say data looked something like:

**file1.csv**

```
id         dates
123        1/1/21
123        2/1/21
123        3/1/21
456        4/1/21 
789        5/1/21
```

**file2.csv**

```
id         dates
123        1/1/21
123        2/1/21
910        6/1/21
```

So basically an id can have multiple dates
I have to make sure that the data in 2 files are accurate meaning,
I will need to make sure that the data in both the files are same,
I should retrieve info thats not in file1 and vice versa.
in the above example the expected output should be something like:

> file2.csv doesnt have a record with id 123 and date 3/1/21, 456 and 789 and file1.csv does not have records with id 910.

Comment: I fixed the formatting in the body of your Question. To show off example data as plain text, wrap your lines with triple back-ticks and specify format as `none`.

Comment: Java is not spelled in all caps. Please be respectful to your readers and use appropriate spelling and case ("I", not "I") as this site is meant to be more like Wikipedia and less like a casual chat room.

Comment: Basil thanks alot for correcting the question and I apologize to everyone if you see something thats not meant to be here, please bare with me as im new to this.